# CHEF log resource log file path

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Where does the CHEF log resource keeps the log files? 
In the CHEF local mode, how can local log file path can be given in Windows?
After chef-client runs locally, the logs should be available in the given log file path.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your configuration. By default, the logs only go to stdout. You can set a file via `--log-location` or `log_location` in your `client.rb`. You can also set the location to `win_evt` to send things to the Windows event log, or `syslog` for Unix syslog.